# Offline orthogonal range counting implementation

Tags: r, computational-geometry

It seems that a statistical problem that I am working on requires doing something known in computational geometry as "offline orthogonal range counting":

Suppose I have a set of *n* points (for the moment, in the plane). For every pair of points *i* and *j*, I would like to count the number of remaining points in the set that are in the rectangle whose diagonal is the segment with endpoints *i* and *j*. The overall output then is a vector of *n(n-1)* values each in *[0, 1, 2, ... , n-2]*.

I've seen that a rich literature on the problem (or at least a very similar problem) exists, but I cannot find an implementation. I would prefer an R (a statistical computing language) package, but I guess that's asking too much. An open source C/C++ implementation will also work.

Thanks.

Comment: There are many rectangles with that diagonal. Do you mean the rectangle having sides parallel to the x and y axes? Also, how many points are likely to be in the patterns you're analyzing (i.e. will computational speed/efficiency matter)?

Comment: I think I know what you are looking for, but mind including an image, or a link to an image? Having trouble finding any visuals.

Comment: Yes: axis-parallel sides

Comment: Yes: a computationally efficient solution is necessary. This plays a part in a rather general modeling / testing approach, so the faster I can make this, the larger problems the approach becomes feasible for.

Comment: @skauf: I am encountering the exact same problem as you (in more than two dimensions). Did you make progress in finding an implementation?

Comment: @bennos: I have, an O(n^2) solution. But it relies on the two dimensional structure, and will not work in higher dimension.

Comment: @skauf: Thanks! Can you share the O(n^2) solution you found, or give a pointer ot it?

Comment: @bennos: The idea is to compute the double cumulative sum over the grid defined by unique values in each axis (can be done in O(n^2)). The sum of points in any single axis-parallel rectangle can then be computed in O(1) from this cumulative sum. Since we have O(n^2) pairs, or rectangles, this thing is overall O(n^2).

Answer (score 0):

I hope I understand well your proble. Here an implementation in R using package `geometry`. I use 
`mesh.drectangle` function which compute a signed distance from points p to boundary of rectangle.

1. I create a combination for all points using `combn`
2. for each point *p* of combination , I compute the distance from the rectangle *rect_p* to the others points
3. if distance < 0 I choose the points.

For example

```
library(geometry)
## I generate some data 
set.seed(1234)
p.x <- sample(1:100,size=30,replace=T)
p.y <- sample(1:100,size=30,replace=T)
points <- cbind(p.x,p.y)

## the  algortithm
ll <- combn(1:nrow(points),2,function(x){
     x1<- p.x[x[1]]; y1 <- p.y[x[1]]
     x2<- p.x[x[2]]; y2 <- p.y[x[2]]
     p <- points[-x,]
     d <- mesh.drectangle(p,x1,y1,x2,y2)
     res <- NA
     if(length(which(d <0))){
        points.in = as.data.frame(p,ncol=2)[ d < 0 , ]
       res <- list(n = nrow(points.in), 
                    rect = list(x1=x1,x2=x2,y1=y1,y2=y2),
                    points.in = points.in)
     }
     res
},simplify=F)
ll <- ll[!is.na(ll)]

## the result
nn <- do.call(rbind,lapply(ll,'[[','n'))
```

To visualize the results, I plots rectangles with 5 points for example.

[image]

```
library(grid)
grid.newpage()
vp <- plotViewport(xscale = extendrange(p.x),
                          yscale = extendrange(p.y))
pushViewport(vp)
grid.xaxis()   
grid.yaxis()
grid.points(x=points[,'p.x'],y=points[,'p.y'],pch='*')
cols <- rainbow(length(ll))
ll <- ll[nn == 5]           ## here I plot only the rectangle with 5 points 
lapply(seq_along(ll),function(i){
            x <- ll[[i]]
            col <- sample(cols,1)
            x1<- x$rect$x1; x2<- x$rect$x2
            y1<- x$rect$y1; y2<- x$rect$y2
            grid.rect(x=(x1+x2)*.5,y=(y1+y2)*.5,
                      width= x2-x1,height = y2-y1,
                      default.units ='native',
                      gp=gpar(fill=col,col='red',alpha=0.2)
                      )
            grid.points(x=x$points.in$p.x,y=x$points.in$p.y,pch=19,
                        gp=gpar(col=rep(col,x$n))) 

 }
)
upViewport()
```

Comment: Thanks. I really like the visualization, it's a great example. I was looking for a more efficient solution than the brute force O(n^3) though. For example an implementation of the algorithm described in [this link](http://people.csail.mit.edu/mip/papers/invs/paper.pdf)

Comment: @skauf thanks I like it too :) 10 mins to apply the algorithm but 3 hours to do the visualization...How do konow it is O(n^3)?